# Javascript: localStorage.getItem(key) not working

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to use local storage to store some texture objects but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem("name" + i, Transition.blurPano.getTexture(path + img_name[i] + ".jpg", dfrd[i], true, i));

    console.log(localStorage.getItem("name" + i) == Transition.blurPano.getTexture(path + img_name[i] + ".jpg", dfrd[i], true, i));

        Transition.blurPano.mesh.material.materials[i].map = localStorage.getItem("name" + i);
    }
```

Here I am trying to store a key value pair in the local storage with `key = "name" + i` and value is the texture object which is returned by the gettexture function, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot store objects in localstorage directly.
A workaround can be to stringify your object before storing it, and later parse it when you retrieve it:

```
var name = { 'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(name));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'));
```

Comment: This solution is not working. It is giving error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Comment: You are getting this error because the response is already parsed.Try to retrieve stored object without using JSON.parse...This will work :)